# Where are Dolphin emulator saves located on a mac?

Tags: emulation, nintendo-gamecube, dolphin-emulator

I am trying to transfer some save files across from Dolphin emulator that I have downloaded manually from their website to the version of Dolphin installed with OpenEMU for mac as the performance is much better on that version of Dolphin than the one I first installed.

I cannot locate the saves on my Mac and I am wondering where they are so I can transfer them across.

I have tried searching the internet and have found plenty for *PC* but not for mac.

Comment: Just a guess but 'Library/Application Support/xxx' in your home directory is a common location for application data. Note that the Library folder is normally hidden by Finder.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know that existed.
All I need to do is move:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Dolphin/GC/USA/Card A
```
to: 
```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/OpenEmu/dolphin/GC/USA/Card A
```

Comment: @greg-449 Can you or OP post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

On macOS applications normally save data in `~/Library/Application Support/xxx` where `~` is your home directory and `xxx` is the application name.

Note that macOS Finder normally hides the Library folder. You can get Finder to show hidden folders with ⌘⇧. (Command+Shift+.). You can also see Library in the Finder `Go` menu by pressing ⌥ when the Go menu is displayed.

Also note that there is also a `Library` folder in the root directory (`/Library`) which is not the folder required here.